# getting Readable { .. } instead of specific collection using find() on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection named 'EloVars' on my mongodb, with only one document:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5800f3bfdcba0f48d2c58161"
},
"nextPID": "0",
"TotalComprasions": "0"
```

}

I'm trying to get the value of nextPID this way:

```
var myDoc = db.collection('EloVars').find();
if(myDoc) {
    console.log('What exactly am I getting here:')
    console.log(myDoc)
    req.body.pid = myDoc.nextPID;
}
```

When I look at the console i noticed that what I'm getting is not 'EloVars' collection... just weired long Readable:

```
  Readable {
  pool: null,
  server: null,
  disconnectHandler: 
   { s: { storedOps: [], storeOptions: [Object], topology: [Object] },
     length: [Getter] },
  bson: {},
  ns: 'mydb.EloVars',
  cmd: 
   { find: 'mydb.EloVars',
     limit: 0,
     skip: 0,
     query: {},
     slaveOk: true,
     readPreference: { preference: 'primary', tags: undefined, options: [Object] } },
  options: 
 .....
 .....
```

What is this readable and why am I getting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` returns a `cursor`. You have to iterate the cursor to get the documents.

```
var cursor = db.collection('EloVars').find();

cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
    console.log(doc);
});
```

Or you can convert it to an array to get the documents.

```
cursor.toArray(function(err, doc){
    console.log(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying in this way? if there is not any specific reason and you just wanted to get "nextPID" the you can use below query:

```
db.collection('EloVars').findOne({},{_id:0, nextPID:1}).exec(function(err, doc) {
if(doc) {
    console.log('What exactly am I getting here:')
    console.log(myDoc)
    req.body.pid = doc.nextPID;
}
})
```

P.S.: it'll get only one nextPID.

to get all:

```
db.collection('EloVars').find({},{_id:0, nextPID:1}).exec(function(err, docs) {
    if(docs && docs.length){
     // your code here
    }
})
```